# One String object plus another String, the result is up to the arguments of the two String object

Tags: java, string

Just run the below codes in **jdk1.8(mine is jdk1.8.0_60)**, the result is:

```
true
false
true,
```

The method `c2()` returns `false`, why?

I just want to know about the runtime constant pool. Not about comparing different strings.

#### Attempt

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        c1();
        c2();
        c3();
    }

    private static void c1() {
        String s1 = new String("a") + new String("b");
        s1.intern();
        String s2 = "ab";
        System.out.println(s1 == s2);
    }

    private static void c2() {
        String s1 = new String("h") + new String("e");
        s1.intern();
        String s2 = "he";
        System.out.println(s1 == s2);
    }

    private static void c3() {
        String s1 = new String("e") + new String("h");
        s1.intern();
        String s2 = "eh";
        System.out.println(s1 == s2);
    }
```

Comment: **Never** call `new String`. Never compare references with `==`.

Comment: Why would this be a bug? This is entering the realms of undefined. Also, you might want to update your jdk.

Comment: I just want to know about the runtime const pool.  Not about comparing different string.

Comment: You know calling `x.intern()` doesn't necessarily make the string object `x` an interned string. It _returns_ an interned instance of the string.

Comment: Have you read the javadoc for String#intern? You seem to be using it incorrectly.

Comment: As an aside: I would suggest it's a bad idea to assume that any behavior you don't understand is likely to be a bug. (The title of the post starting "a jvm bug?".) Always assume that it's a failing on your part (of understanding or of code) until you can prove otherwise. Almost every bug I've ever encountered was my own fault, and I suspect most developers have the same experience - proceeding with that *expectation* is much more helpful than assuming that every problem is someone else's fault.

Comment: @Jon Skeet   All right. Sorry. I just want to attact your foucs.  Now I have changed it

Comment: @Mr.H: You mean you use "a jvm bug?" as clickbait, effectively? Please don't do that again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you're detecting here is that by the time you reach your `main` method, `"he"` is already in the constant pool, but `"ab"` and `"eh"` aren't.

Therefore while `c1` and `c3` add your "new" strings to the constant pool when you call `intern`, in `c2` the *existing* string is returned by `intern` - so if you change your code to

```java
private static void c2() {
    String s1 = new String("h") + new String("e");
    s1 = s1.intern();
    String s2 = "he";
    System.out.println(s1 == s2);
}
```

... you'll see that prints `true`.

Alternatively, to make `c1` print `false`, just force `"ab"` into the constant pool to start with:

```java
public static final String foo = "ab";
```

Now `"ab"` is in the constant pool before `c1` runs, so again, `s1.intern()` doesn't add anything to the constant pool, and the reference comparison prints `false`.